# Main Ideas behind Spanish Game, Cozio Defense

Tags: opening, theory, positional-play

I've been practicing the Spanish Game so I can have better tournament results with it,

**Spanish Game**

```
1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6
```

**Spanish Game, Cozio Defense**

and I asked my friend to play the Cozio defense,

```
1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Bb5 Nge7
```

And the game that popped up was

```
rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1

1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Bb5 Nge7 4. Nc3 g6 ({Center control}) 5.d4 exd4 6.Nd5 Nxd5 7. exd5 Qe7+ 8. Kf1 Ne5 {Either way I can't castle, but since I have space I'll keep my queen} 9. Qxd4 Bg7 {Pin the knight to the rook, and I have decent control over white squares and development so I didn't feel threatened that bad and nabbed the pawn} 10. Bf4 f6 {Really good spot to develop and incorporate bishop with some unfinished ideas of attacks} 11. Re1 O-O
```

From here came a bunch of exchanges initiated by white that lead to a slow endgame and draw.

What are the main ideas and advantages of this opening?

---

P.S I don't think Nxd5 was the strongest move from analysing it in an engine and noticing it in the game I had tempo on the e5 square.

and my comments on the moves didn't show in the pgn (I'm not quite sure how to annotate those), but the basic idea was I am a positional player.

-I am playing White

Comment: If I understand well, you are playing White ?

Comment: Yes, I’ll add that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, 6...Nxd5 is not the main line. I remember some games with 6...Bg7 7.Bg5 h6 8.Bf6 Kf8, which is supposed to be a normal line, playable for Black.

In your game continuation, 8.Be2, keeping castling rights, looks good, e.g. 8...Ne5 9.0-0 Bg7 10.Re1 0-0 11.Nxd4 d6 12.f4 with a better development.